# Narrowing scope of C# MVC Routing to a namespace or partial group of controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two different categories of endpoints on a single C# site:

1) A normal MVC site serving up html

2) A JSON API

I'm looking for a way to route requests starting with `api` only to API controllers, and everything else through the normal MVC controllers.

The two groups of controllers are in different namespaces, but apparently when it's building these routes, it looks at all namespaces?

What I have below won't work because, essentially, the second group is too permissive and will route to API controllers, but I'm not sure what to do instead to scope or namespace these requests.

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Api",
        url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional  }
      );

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
      );
```

Comment: `What I have below won't work because, essentially, the second group is too permissive and will route to API controllers` -- No, your first route will get those.  Routes are processed *in order,* which is why you start with the most specific ones and work towards the most general ones, until you finally have a default route at the bottom that catches anything else that falls out of the other routes.

Comment: My problem is that the second group would _also_ route to my API controllers.  If I have an API controller that doesn't have an identically named "regular" controller, then I have an additional route that I did not want, right?  If I don't have a `users` page, but I have an API endpoint, then you could see it at both /api/users/ and /users/.  I don't want the second one to route to any API controller.

Comment: You need to set things up so that *all* of your API calls will get caught by the first MapRoute (or however many you set up for API's).  The subsequent MapRoute(s) won't map any API calls because there won't be any left to route.